# Read list/array out of string

Tags: string, kotlin

Below is how my data looks:

```
val testArray = "["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]"
```

It's an array within a string. I want to get the array/list out of string. Something like:

```
val testArray = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
```

I tried: `val testArray = "["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]" as List<*>`, but the output was null. I also tried `val testArray = "["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]".toList()`, but this returns list of characters.

Is there an easy way in Kotlin to read array from string?

Comment: This is a JSON array of srings. Use any JSON parser.

Comment: @JBNizet - You were right. I converted it to JSONArray(testArray) and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

As @JB said it is JSON array, you can convert it. However if you manually want to do that, you can check this

```
  val str="\"[\"Test1\", \"Test2\", \"Test3\"]\"";

  var list:List<String>?=null
      if(str.length>2)
      list=str.substring(2,str.length-2).split(",").map { it.trim() }.toList()

  print(list)
```